# Can we use 'using ...' with parameter pack name?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, overloading

Suppose we have the following 'overloaded lambdas' template for 2 versions (taken from [here](https://ngathanasiou.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/lambda-hackery-overloading-sfinae-and-copyrights/)):

```
template <class F1, class F2>
struct overload_set : F1, F2
{
    overload_set(F1 x1, F2 x2) : F1(x1), F2(x2) {}
    using F1::operator();
    using F2::operator();
};

template <class F1, class F2>
overload_set<F1,F2> overload(F1 x1, F2 x2)
{
    return overload_set<F1,F2>(x1,x2);
}
```

which we can use like so:

```
auto f = overload (
    []( int) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }, 
    [](char) { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }
);

f('k');
f( 2 );
```

Now the question is whether we can make a generic approach to this?
I have tried with the following (implementation from the same website):

```
template <class... F>
struct overload_set : F... 
{
  overload_set(F... f) : F(f)... {}  
};

template <class... F>
auto overload(F... f) 
{
  return overload_set<F...>(f...);   
}
```

but then I get:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:59:6: error: request for member ‘operator()’ is ambiguous
   f(1);
      ^
main.cpp:51:14: note: candidates are: main()::<lambda(char)>
       [](char) { cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; });
              ^
main.cpp:50:13: note:                 main()::<lambda(int)>
       [](int) { cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; },
             ^
main.cpp:60:8: error: request for member ‘operator()’ is ambiguous
   f('a');
        ^
main.cpp:51:14: note: candidates are: main()::<lambda(char)>
       [](char) { cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; });
              ^
main.cpp:50:13: note:                 main()::<lambda(int)>
       [](int) { cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; },
```

Comment: Instead of a single `using F::operator()...;` one can recursively bring those operators [with inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32476942/3953764)

Comment: Hmm. That other question is about pretty much the same code, the question about the code is different, but the answer works here too. I suspect it'd be okay to close this as a duplicate. If there's some aspect of your question not adequately answered there, can you edit your question to expand on that? Or is it okay to simply close this question?

Comment: @hvd Yup, the answer in linked question works as I wanted. We can close this then.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki You're right. Let's close this one.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, done.

Comment: @Patryk Note that the linked answer provides linear inheritance.  If using a large number of parents (say, more than a few 100), you really want binary tree inheritance, which is trickier.  If you don't have a risk of that, then use linear inheritance.